# Importing Data In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import data from a file `dateUpdated.js` into a `Header.js` file in React.

I am getting an error `TypeError: Object is not a function or its return value is not iterable`, but I have seen it done this way before.

```
    let dateUpdated = {
        "date": [
            {
                "date": "7/10/2021"
            }
        ]
    
    
    }
```

```
import React, {setState} from "react"
import dateUpdated from "../data/dateUpdated"

function Header() {
    const [date, setDate] = setState(dateUpdated)


    return (
        <div>
            <h1></h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    )


}


export default Header
```

Comment: Have you tried console.log dataUpdated?

Comment: Can you update your question to include a full/complete code example? What is the default export from `"../data/dateUpdated"`? Can you include the actual error message and stacktrace? What is `setState`, did you mean to use the `useState` hook?

Comment: are you actually exporting dateUpdated?

Comment: Sorry I meant useState. I am trying to console.log(date) but either i get undefined or and empty object depending on how i word it in the dateUpdated.js file

Comment: As mentioned you probably didn't export your variable. Use export default at the end of the "data" file.

Comment: Where are you console logging anything? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example We can't help fix code we can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you have to export the dateUpdated

Secondly, I think you are trying to use useState hook. SetState, is used react class based components, where you can modify the state value.

```
// Header.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import dateUpdated from "./data";

function Header() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(dateUpdated);
  console.log(date);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

And

```
// data.js

let dateUpdated = {
  date: [
    {
      date: "7/10/2021"
    }
  ]
};
export default dateUpdated;
```

I have created [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wescoff-qd4r6?file=/src/Header.js) for you, look at the codes, you'll understand

Comment: A link to a sandbox is helpful, but you should post the relevant code here, too.

Comment: @Tom you mean posting the code and sandbox link at the same time?

Comment: @DoryNguyen Yes, obviously. The code included in answer stays with the answer, the codesandbox link can die at any moment.

Comment: Yes. The sandbox is not necessary (but is permitted and may indeed be helpful).

Comment: Thanks @Tom for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You are using functional components. Try `useState` instead:

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import dateUpdated from "../data/dateUpdated"

function Header() {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(dateUpdated)


    return (
        <div>
            <h1></h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    )


}


export default Header
```

`setState()` is for class component while `useState()` is for functional component

Secondly, you need to export in dateUpdated.js. This is how I often do it. The function is quite redundant, but I guess we often have to do something with the data before exporting it:

```
const Data = () => {
    return [{"your data": "here"}]
}

export default Data;
```

Then `import` it:

```
import Data from "./data";

const data = Data();
```

Now you can use `data` in your function.

Comment: Sorry i meant useState. When I console.log(date) i get undefined or an empty object.

Comment: Please try my updated answer. This always works for me